# Progress Bar Not Appearing

Tags: c++, winapi

What is incorrect with this piece of code?

I want a progress bar to appear, but instead I get nothing.
I've copyed the code from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmWToGl6GE4), but not the setup of the window.

This isn't all of my program, so maybe there's a mess-up with the code there.

If you want all the code, just ask and I will edit it all in.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>

// PB Defines
HINSTANCE hInstance;
HWND hProgress;
DWORD IDC_TIMER;
DWORD nCounter;

// Window #defines
#define WNDNAME L"ProgressBar"
#define WND_CLASS L"ProgressBarclass"


#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int main() {}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow) {

    hInstance = hInst;

    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };

    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;

    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

    wc.hInstance = hInst;

    wc.lpszClassName = WND_CLASS;

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;

    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc)) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Register Failed", "Register Failed", MB_OK);
    }
    
    CreateWindowW(WND_CLASS, WNDNAME, WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_VISIBLE,
 625, 200, 650, 750, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    


    MSG msg = { 0 };

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }


    return 0;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG: {
        hProgress = CreateWindowEx(0, PROGRESS_CLASS, (LPTSTR)NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | PBS_SMOOTH, 45, 625, 300, 35,
            hWnd, (HMENU)0, hInstance, NULL);
        SendMessage(hProgress, PBM_SETRANGE, 0, MAKELPARAM(0, 100));
        SendMessage(hProgress, PBM_SETSTEP, (WPARAM)10, 0);
        SetTimer(hWnd, IDC_TIMER, 100, 0);
        nCounter = 0;
        break;
    }
    case WM_TIMER: {
        nCounter++;
        SendMessage(hProgress, PBM_STEPIT, 0, 0);
        if (nCounter == 10) {
            KillTimer(hWnd, IDC_TIMER);
        }
        break;
    }
        
    case WM_CREATE:
        break;
        
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(-1);
        break;
        
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
}
```

Using Visual Studio, and Win10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @clouded: if you want to comment to an answer, please attach it your comment to the answer instead of attaching it to your own question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating your main window using [`CreateWindowW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindoww), which does not send [`WM_INITDIALOG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-initdialog), so you are never creating your progress bar or timer.  That is why you are not seeing them do anything.

The code in the video is creating its main window using [`DialogBox()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dialogboxw) instead of [`CreateWindowW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindoww).  [`DialogBox()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dialogboxw) sends [`WM_INITDIALOG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-initdialog) (hence the name).

When using [`CreateWindowW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindoww), you need to move your [`WM_INITDIALOG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-initdialog) logic into [`WM_CREATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-create) instead.